# Make node dump performance map continuously or on non-clean exit

Tags: node.js, performance

I'm attempting to create a flame graph for a Node app that's causing some issues, and while I am able to profile it using Xcode and get its CPU trace, the Node `perf` map isn't dumping to, for example, `/tmp/perf-30001.map`, when I exit it uncleanly (unfortunately, the issue I'm running into isn't allowing me to exit the Node app cleanly). I'm running the app with the `--perf-basic-prof` flag.

Is there any way to get Node to dump the memory map either continuously or on any kind of exit?

Answer (score 0):

The map file is written continuously, be sure to use at least node 0.12 and to disable kptr_restrict `sudo sysctl kernel/kptr_restrict=0`.

And if you want a memory dump at exit you can later open in v8 debugger :

```
var heapdump = require('heapdump');
process.on('exit', function() {
  heapdump.writeSnapshot(Date.now() + '.heapsnapshot');
});
```